# UWP with BingMaps Crashes on WindowsServer 2019

Tags: uwp, bing-maps, windows-server

My UWP-APP contains only a MapControl.

This APP crashes on  WindowsServer 2019 Ver. 1809 (Build 17763.1075)

It runs fine on WindowsServer 2019 Vers. 1809 (Build 17763.737)

I've tried to create the control in code behind surrounded with a try. The APP crashes also. But i got the following exception:

********** 11.03.2020 09:49:39 ********** 
Exception Type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
Exception: External component has thrown an exception.
Source: 
Stack Trace: 
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl..ctor()
   at airformManager.PlannerViews.AboutPage.Page_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

In the event log i've got an entry:

Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apps using the MapControl will crash unless the Downloaded Maps Manager service is enabled.](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2069707) The Downloaded Maps Manager service is disabled by default on Windows Server.

On later versions of Windows (1903+), the MapControl won't crash if the service is disabled, but it still won't be able to load any map data. Your app can handle this by checking if the [LoadingStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.loadingstatuschanged) of the MapControl is [MapLoadingStatus.DownloadedMapsManagerUnavailable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.maploadingstatus).